# Reading Time Data using INFILE option

Tags: sas

I have a .csv file which has some flight information. Sample data is shown below.

```
date|sched_dep_time|dep_time|sched_arr_time|arr_time
1/1/2013|515|517|819|830
```

The 515 here actually means 5:15Hrs. How can I read this data into SAS correctly? If I use the time. format, it is coming up with some strange timings. I have seen some code snippets, which has to be written exclusively to do these time conversions. But is there are more straight forward method available?

Answer (score 1):

Use the informat HHMMSS, which will read it in correctly.

```
data have;
informat date ddmmyy10. sched_dep_time dep_time sched_arr_time arr_time hhmmss.;
format sched_dep_time dep_time sched_arr_time arr_time time.;
input date sched_dep_time dep_time sched_arr_time arr_time;
cards;
1/1/2013 515 517 819 830
;
run;

proc print data=have;run;
```

Comment: @user3831696  : It is nice for the time, but only add FORMAT DATE DDMMYY10. to have the good date format.

Comment: Tried this. This is the output I get.
01/01/2013 0:08:35 0:08:37 0:13:39
Note the additional 0: coming at the start. The output I require is 08:35 (i.e 8 hrs 35 mins).

Comment: From the exact code above or when used with your own data? The code above works fine for me, using SAS 9.4 TS1M3. If it's your own data, edit your question to include the new information but it means that your example is different than your actual data somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize the HHMMSS. INFORMAT would work.  Reeza's answer is best.  If you want a custom function, here you go.

```
options cmplib=work.fns;

proc fcmp outlib=work.fns.time;
function to_time(x);
    minutes = mod(x,100);
    hour = (x-minutes)/100;
    time = hms(hour,minutes,0);
    return (time);
endsub;
run;

data test;
format in_val   best. 
       out_time time.;
in_val = 512;
out_time = to_time(in_val);
put in_val out_time;
run;
```